# Making an element resize while being dragged from its centre

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drag-and-drop, drag

I want an element to resize based upon its location within the parent while its being dragged from its centre.

The problem is that the draggable elements moves away from the cursor while being dragged.

The [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KtrhL/2/) should make it clear what the intention is.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtrhL/2/)

Javascript Code:

```
var ele     = document.getElementsByClassName ("target")[0];
var parent  = document.getElementsByClassName ("containerParent")[0];
var mouseDownIs = false;
ele.addEventListener ("mousedown" , eleMouseDown , false);

function eleMouseDown () {
    mouseDownIs = true;
    document.addEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
}

function eleMouseMove (ev) {
    if (mouseDownIs === true) {
        var pX  = ev.pageX;
        var pY  = ev.pageY;
        var inParentPosX= pX - parent.offsetLeft;
        var inParentPosY= pY - parent.offsetTop;
        var mFactor     = 0.12; // ratio -> half parent divided by child width
        if  (inParentPosX > 125) { // first edge case scenario; restrict max size of draggable element (child)
            var result      = (125 * mFactor);
        }   else if (inParentPosX <= 25) { // second edge case scenario; restrict min size of draggable element (child)
            var result  = (25 * mFactor);
           }    else    {
            var result  = (inParentPosX * mFactor);
        }
// This is where things are probably going wrong
        var posX        = inParentPosX + ((result - 2) / 2); // -2 is for the border value
        var posY        = inParentPosY + ((result - 2) / 2);
        ele.style.left  = posX + "px";
        ele.style.top   = posY + "px";
        ele.style.width = result + "px";
        ele.style.height= result + "px";
    }
    document.addEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}

function eleMouseUp () {
    mouseDownIs = false;
    document.removeEventListener ("mousemove" , eleMouseMove , false);
    document.removeEventListener ("mouseup" , eleMouseUp , false);
}
```

This is a repost of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465730/drag-a-dynamically-resizing-element-from-the-centre) I posted yesterday which only get only 13 views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var posX = inParentPosX + ((result - 2) / 2);
var posY = inParentPosY + ((result - 2) / 2);
```

should be

```
var posX = inParentPosX - ((result - 2) / 2);
var posY = inParentPosY - ((result - 2) / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you & I cant believe I was making such a silly mistake. Many thanks sza. One minor correction: It should be: var posX = inParentPosX - (result / 2);
var posY = inParentPosY - (result / 2);

Comment: @Kayote right, if you take off the border delta, it looks better.